# React pdf viewer - using worker from local server

Tags: reactjs, pdf, web-worker

I am considering using a react pdf viewer package that I found [here](https://react-pdf-viewer.dev/docs/basic-usage). In the docs it says that you should set the worker like this:

*It's up to you to use the pdf.worker.min.js file from popular services, such as
https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.5.207/build/pdf.worker.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.5.207/pdf.worker.min.js
or download and store it on your server.*

And this is the example for using the worker from external service:

```
<Worker workerUrl="https://unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@2.5.207/build/pdf.worker.min.js">
    <!-- The viewer component will be put here -->
    ...
</Worker>
```

But, if I am to use this package, I need the worker to be locally, I can't use external urls. There is no example of local usage of a worker. How can I set this up in a react app created with create react app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can figure it out using [pdfjs-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist)
And then can use it locally.

```
 const pdfjs = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
 const pdfjsWorker = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.entry');

 pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = pdfjsWorker;
```

[SOURCE](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/8305)